# Named view dashboard not working with child view

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-router

i have defined my state like this below.

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngSanitize',

    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.jq',

    'abp'
]);

//Configuration for Angular UI routing.
app.config([
    '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: '/App/Main/views/home/home.cshtml',
                menu: 'Home' //Matches to name of 'Home' menu in EMRNavigationProvider
            })
            .state('personview', {
                url: '/person/view',
                templateUrl: '/App/Main/views/person/view/index.cshtml',
                views: {
                    "viewTop": { templateUrl: "/App/Main/views/person/view/viewTop.cshtml" },
                    "viewMain": { templateUrl: "/App/Main/views/person/view/viewMain.cshtml" },
                    "viewAllergies": { templateUrl: "/App/Main/views/person/view/allergies.cshtml" },
                    "viewAppointments": { templateUrl: "/App/Main/views/person/view/appointments.cshtml" },
                    "viewimmunization": { templateUrl: "/App/Main/views/person/view/immunization.cshtml" },
                    "viewNotes": { templateUrl: "/App/Main/views/person/view/notes.cshtml" },
                },
                menu: 'ViewPerson',
            })
            .state('personsearch', {
                url: '/person/search',
                templateUrl: '/App/Main/views/home/home.cshtml',
                menu: 'SearchPerson'
            })
        ;
    }
]);
```

my index.cshtml for multiple named view looks like

```
<div class="right_col" role="main">
    545465464646454545
    <div ui-view="viewTop"></div>
    <div ui-view="viewMain"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div ui-view="viewAllergies"></div>
        <div ui-view="viewAppointments"></div>
        <div ui-view="viewimmunization"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div ui-view="viewNotes"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason when i  browse to http://myhost/#/person/view  it gives me content for my home page and not the dashboard view (multiple named view) i was hoping with personview from above route.

if i remove property views from 'personview' named view it displays my hard coded 545465464646454545 correctly in screen and does not give content for home page.this tells me that having child views: under the route is not working.

what is wrong with route above for multiple named views that it does not like to render?

Comment: can you please provide a plunker?

Comment: Take a look in browser dev tools network and see if any of the template requests are failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must modify code like this:

Template index.cshtml must have tag `<div ui-view="content"></div>` and may include viewTop, viewMain

Template View.cshtml consists one of templates: viewAllergies, viewAppointments etc.

```
app.config([
'$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('person', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '/',
            template:'<div ui-view=""></div>'
        })
        .state('person.view', {
            url: '/personview',
            views: {
             '': {
                templateUrl: '/App/Main/views/person/view/index.cshtml'
             },
             'content@person.view': {
                templateUrl: '/App/Main/views/person/view/View.cshtml'
             }
            }
        })          
}
```

]);

Comment: tired this way did not work either, added <div  ui-view="content" class="right_col" role="main">   in index and no lucj

Comment: In app.js you find work example http://utkinolegv.github.io/angular-simple-site.github.io/